# Counting files commands in a loop

Tags: shell-script

How can I use `ls *.txt | wc` as a separate variable so I can use it in a loop afterwards? That is

```
count.files=$(ls *.txt | wc)
...

if count.files -ne 2000; then
echo "message"
fi
```

I  have tried it but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: `count_files=$(ls *.txt | wc -l);if [ ${count_files} -ne 2000 ]; then echo "message";fi`

Comment: You have syntax problems. Missing `$` in variable substitution and missing `[]` brackets for `-ne` to make sense.

Comment: It should be noted that all of the answers provided so far do not provide a mechanism for decreasing the count stored in the variable. Unless this `if` is only a member of a loop that *does* include some mechanism to decrease the number of files being counted, this will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: If you are using this counter to iterate over files with a loop, I should point out this possibly the worst way of doing it. Do you need `for file in *.txt; do ...; done` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in you code:

- in most shells, a variable name cannot contain a dot
- you need to call `wc` with the `-l` flag
- you need to call `ls` with the `-d` flag
- you need to mark the end of options with `--` or use a `./` prefix for `ls`
- your `if` test misses brackets (but maybe that's just stackexchange formatting)
- that won't work if file names contain newline characters
- that omits hidden files.

Here is a better working example:

```
file_count=$(ls -d ./*.txt | wc -l)
if [ $file_count -ne 2000 ]; then echo "message"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the feature you're thinking of is disciplines. That's a `ksh93`-only feature:

```
function count.get {
  .sh.value=$(set -- ~(N)*.txt; echo "$#")
}
```

Then, whenever `$count` is expanded, that *discipline* function is invoked that assigns a value to it.

In `zsh`, you can also define the content of a variable as code:

```
count='$(set -- *.txt(N); echo "$#")'
```

and use it as `${(e)count}` for that code to be <kbd>e</kbd>valuated upon expansion.

However those give little benefit over the standard way of using a function:

```
count() (
  set -- [*].txt *.txt
  case $1$2 in
    '[*].txt*.txt') echo 0;;
    *) echo "$#"
  esac
)
```

(the `[*]` trick can be avoided with shells that support nullglob options (like `ksh93`'s `~(N)` or `zsh`'s `(N)` above)).

And use it as `$(count)` (*command substitution*).

(see the other answers for all the issues with your code).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use `wc -l` to count only newlines. This should work:

```
#!
filecounter=$(ls *.txt | wc -l)
if [ $filecounter -ne 2000 ]; then echo "message"
fi
```